# Vector Algebra - tetrahedron question

Tags: geometry, vectors

> OABC is a tetrahedron with OA = a, OB = b, OC = c. P and Q are mid points of OA and BC respectively. Find in terms of a, b, c the position vector of the mid-point of PQ relative to O as the origin, and hence deduce that the lines joining the mid-points of opposite edges of a tetrahedron are concurrent and bisect each other.

[image]

First, $OA = a$, since P is at the mid-point of OA,
$$OP = \frac{a}{2}$$

Using section formula:

$$OQ=\frac{b+c}{2}$$

Mid-point of PQ has a position vector of:
$$OM=\frac{\frac{a+b+c}{2}}{2}=\frac{a+b+c}{4}$$

I don't know how to prove that they are concurrent and that they bisect each other.

Comment: The midpoint of $PQ$ is not $\frac{1}{2} PQ$. It as a point $M$ such that $OM = \frac{1}{2}(OP + OQ)$. The vector $\frac{1}{2} PQ$ is the vector $PM$.

Comment: @Gribouillis Whoops, you're right. That was silly. FIxed it.

Comment: Now choose two other opposite edges with mid-points $P', Q'$ and do the same.